# Parser Error: Unexpected token , expected identifier or keyword at the end of the expression

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to show the data of an API I get an error.
What I want is to show each of the data, I will leave the URL of the API in case you want to analyze it.
https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/civilizations

**civilizationes.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GameService } from '../../services/game.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-civilizaciones',
  templateUrl: './civilizaciones.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./civilizaciones.component.css']
})
export class CivilizacionesComponent implements OnInit {

  civilizaciones: any = [];

  constructor(private gameService: GameService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gameService.getCivilizations().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.civilizaciones = res;
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
}
```

**civilizationes.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let civilizacion of civilizaciones">
    <td>{{civilizacion.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**API**

```
{
  "civilizations": [
    {
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "Aztecs", 
      "expansion": "The Conquerors", 
      "army_type": "Infantry and Monk", 
      "unique_unit": [
        "https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/unit/jaguar_warrior"
      ], 
      "unique_tech": [
        "https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/technology/garland_wars"
      ], 
      "team_bonus": "Relics generate +33% gold", 
      "civilization_bonus": [
        "Villagers carry +5", 
        "Military units created 15% faster", 
        "+5 Monk hit points for each Monastery technology", 
        "Loom free"
      ]
    },
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Where is the source for `CivilizacionesComponent.html`? It looks like you're missing a property name after `civilization.` in the template.

Comment: you're reffering to template `civilizaciones.component.html` but in the question you've posted, `civilizations.component.html` it may be that you've multiple templates and in `civilizaciones.component.html` there is this syntax error.

Comment: @MattU 
I'm sorry, all you call civilizationes.component

Comment: @Minato I'm sorry, all you call civilizationes.component

Comment: @LuisFernandoSilva I am talking about line `templateUrl: './civilizaciones.component.html',` in you `civilizationes.component.ts`

Comment: @Minato 
Everything is in order

Comment: @Minato 
Doing it with proxy influences?

Comment: @LuisFernandoSilva look for this `./civilizaciones.component.html` file in the folder where you have the component

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<tr *ngFor="let civilizacion of civilizaciones.civilizations">
    <td>{{civilizacion.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from api has a root property named `civilizations` so you need to assign it instead of response itself.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.gameService.getCivilizations().subscribe(
      res => {
         this.civilizaciones = res.civilizations; 
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please add further information about how this code does

Comment: @GastónSaillén is this solution

Comment: yes, I mean, you can also elaborate what this code does and how it solves the problem, it will be better for others to understand what it does